# How to find what engine (gem) provides a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-engines

One of my gems, a Rails Engine, provides a route that should not be there. And I would like to find out what gem that is.

This is a Spree site, with a few extensions, so quite a lot of small engines that come with dependencies: one of these is offering `admin/login` which should not be there. When I build a "vanilla" spree site, that route is not there, yet in my old and upgraded-over-time instance, it is.

Is there a way to quickly get a list of all routes grouped by the file or engine they are defined in?

Comment: Mhhh good point. Can `rake routes` be of any help in this case? In theory, shows what controller each route is linked to, it can help. Far from perfect, but you can understand which engine is from the controller class, maybe

Comment: Yes, but, strange as it may be, the gem providing the controller (spree_auth_device) does not provide the route. At least not from what I can see. I now realize that I did not try the most obvious: enable/disable the gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick and dirty solution**

I don't know if Rails can do this for specific routes. I'm assuming you haven't bundled a lot of gems that set up routes.

`bundle show --paths` lists the paths of all gems that are required by your Gemfile.

Given that Rails engines also [draw their routes in `config/routes.rb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes), you can find those files using Bundler and UNIX tools:

```
find `bundle show --paths` -name routes.rb | grep -v test | grep -v spec
```

You will not find a specific route with this but it should give you a hint where to look...

Comment: I already tried grepping, but the weird thing is that the routes don't show up when I search very specific strings (`admin/login`) and far too much when I search for parts (`admin` or `login`). Yet in the last case, I still had no starting-point to start searching.